# Java Web Start application shows empty window on XMonad

Tags: java, linux, java-web-start, xmonad

I use XMonad+gnome as window Manager. I have the problem that, when I run a Java Web Start applicacion, It olways show an empty window, like the screen:

[image: screen]

Is there something I can do to fix it?

UPDATE:

I tried simple programs from [JWS Examples](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/uiswing/learn/example-1dot4/index.html) and it works, right. So it should be a problem of the application.

The failed aaplication is Blast2Go.

Comment: All JWS applications or just one?

Comment: @trashgod, I tested another long time ago, and also have the problem. This appplication with Ubuntu+Unity works right.

Comment: It may be a problem with [tag:xmonad]. Find a short, publicly available, JWS [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) that fails with xmonad and works with other window managers. Update your question to cite the example.

Comment: @trashgod  Good idea.  ..Do you have problems with any of [these demos](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html)?  They are all small & from my site.  One of them requires trust, ignore it and try the others which are sand-boxed.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, no I haven't problems with your demos.

Comment: OK.  Thanks for that info.  Try some of the ones in the Java tutorial.  I suspect this is a problem with the app. itself.  Most likely (of a vast range of possibilities) would be adding everything to the content pane, calling set size, but forgetting to invoke `pack()` at any point.  I think @trashgod also has some JWS based apps., but if mine worked for you, I'd bet those will as well.

Comment: As @AndrewThompson suggests, I often cite this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway); see also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12552541/230513) about calling `setVisible()` _last_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the name of the window manager to a known one like `LG3D`:

```
startupHook = setWMName "LG3D"
```

Comment: I used this method. But it is also possible to downgrade to Java 1.6. For Fedora you can use these instructions http://superuser.com/questions/441757/how-install-older-openjdk-1-6-in-fedora-17.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with my own Java code and using the other suggested solutions (setWMName, MToolkit, etc.) did not solve the problem with Xmonad. I must note that in other window managers (e.g. fluxbox), the app works as expected. In my case, however, I figured out the problem. If you have access to the source of the Java app, I suggest you consider the following:

If you have any JFrame or JPanel or other containers, you should explicitly define their layouts. If you set the layout to null, then the dimensions of the container must be set explicitly. Otherwise, the container won't be rendered at all. For instance, I have a JPanel that contains all my widgets. I'd rather have full control over the layout, so I set the layout to null, and then explicitly set the dimensions for the JPanel:

```
jContentPane.setLayout(null);
jContentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(appletWidth,appletHeight+100));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have access to the code, but your solution should be notice.